# Paypal: 403 Post Error (react-paypal-button-v2)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal

So i've been messing with this for a few days, but no luck.

Around 80% of the time checking out with Paypal on my website, I get a 403 POST error. It seems to happen at random, but I have no clue why that would be happening. It certainly works sometimes, but here's the error when it doesn't:

[image]

And here's the code for my button. When the error occours, "onSuccess()" is never called, and the window just kind of closes itself without any warning. onError() or onCancel are never called either, making this a very strange error.

```
<PayPalButton style={{ height: 55, }} 
shippingPreference="NO_SHIPPING" 
amount={this.props.total} 
onCancel={(e) => this.cancelPaypal()} 
onClick={(e) => this.checkCart(e)} 
onError={(e) => { console.log(e); alert("error"); }} 
onSuccess={(details, data) => { 
this.setState({ error: null, succeeded: true, processing: false, loadingIcon: false, });
 }}
options={{
      clientId: myClientId,
      currency: "USD",
      disableFunding: "card,credit",
        }}
/>
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It occurs whenever I click the final "Pay now" button on the Paypal modal. Everything up to that point is fine.

Not sure what to do, I have no clue why this would happen. Since it works sometimes, it can't be a bad id on myPart. Thanks everyone...

EDIT: I don't know what this means, but here is the 'Capture' error when I click the error link: [image]

Comment: With the 403 error selected as in your last screenshot, click on `Response` on the right to get the actual json data details about the capture error

Comment: I am getting the exact same issue. Seems to be random and only started happening today. The response tab contains Error 403, varnish cache server, guru meditation. Its really annoying

Comment: @Kurtis very strange... Well, hopefully they fix it soon then!